# Looking for advice setting up a new Mac Mini with Lion Server

Tags: security, macos

I am setting up a new Mac Mini server which will serve as a web server (with Apache and MySQL) as well as some other pieces of functionality.  I have seen little on securing OS X for such a scenario (I am running Lion - and this is not Lion Sever).

I assume it is recommended to use ipfw as opposed to the application firewall.  I also assume that it makes sense to lock down SSH (put it on a non-standard port and use certificate authentication).  However, should I also lock down screen sharing (and force an SSH tunnel for this)?  Any tips on this are welcome.

Comment: Don't use LDAP for user authentication until it actually checks more than whether any text is entered in the user field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although written for 10.5, [this guide by Daniel Cuthbert](http://research.corsaire.com/whitepapers/080818-securing-mac-os-x-leopard.pdf) (PDF) is fairly comprehensive and largely still applies to Lion.

Closing off screen sharing and tunneling it (if you need it at all) through SSH is probably a good idea.

Standard rules apply:

- Only open absolutely necessary ports to the outside world
- Keep your software up to date
- Disable any unused services & Apache modules
- Disable any listeners you don't need, rebind those you do need to localhost only if they're not needed outside (`lsof -i` is your friend)
- Check that your firewall is really working as expected (`nmap` from an outside host)

Mac specific things:

- Make sure the console is password protected, locks if you're using screensharing and doesn't auto-login on startup
- You may want to enable verbose boot messages by default, it'll make debugging easier in case things go bad: `sudo nvram boot-args="-v"`